# Proof of Peikert's fact 2.1 about multiplication of two n-dimensional Gaussian functions

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I want to prove the theorem in Peikert's paper (Fact 2.1):

- Chris Peikert, [An efficient and parallel Gaussian sampler for lattices](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-14623-7_5) [[PDF](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/088.pdf)], 2011.

Let $\rho_{\sqrt{\Sigma}}(\textbf{x}) \triangleq \exp (-\pi \cdot \textbf{x}^t \Sigma^{-1} \textbf{x})$ be the $n$-dimensional Gaussian function mapping $\mathbb{R}^n \to (0,1]$, where $\Sigma$ is some positive definite matrix. Its statement is given below:

> Let $\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2 > 0$ be positive definite matrices, let $\Sigma_0 = \Sigma_1+\Sigma_2 > 0$ and $\Sigma_3^{-1} = \Sigma_1^{-1} + \Sigma_2^{-1} > 0$, let $\textbf{x}, \textbf{c}_1, \textbf{c}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be arbitrary, and let $\textbf{c}_3 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be such that $\Sigma_3^{-1}\textbf{c}_3 = \Sigma_1^{-1}\textbf{c}_1 + \Sigma_2^{-1}\textbf{c}_2$. Then
> $$
> \rho_{\sqrt{\Sigma}_1}(\textbf{x}-\textbf{c}_1) \cdot \rho_{\sqrt{\Sigma}_2}(\textbf{x}-\textbf{c}_2)
> =
> \rho_{\sqrt{\Sigma}_0}(\textbf{c}_1-\textbf{c}_2) \cdot \rho_{\sqrt{\Sigma}_3}(\textbf{x}-\textbf{c}_3)
> $$

My idea:

I have tried to expand the LHS and RHS to get the following:

$$
\textbf{c}_1^t\Sigma_1^{-1}\textbf{c}_1 + \textbf{c}_2^t\Sigma_2^{-1}\textbf{c}_2 = \textbf{c}_1^t\Sigma_0^{-1}\textbf{c}_1 - \textbf{c}_1^t\Sigma_0^{-1}\textbf{c}_2 - \textbf{c}_2^t\Sigma_0^{-1}\textbf{c}_1 + \textbf{c}_2^t\Sigma_0^{-1}\textbf{c}_2 + \textbf{c}_3^t\Sigma_3^{-1}\textbf{c}_3
$$
But I don't know how to keep going.

Besides, the author provided a hint about the fact $\Sigma_3^{-1} = \Sigma_1^{-1} + \Sigma_2^{-1} = \Sigma_1^{-1} \cdot (\Sigma_1 + \Sigma_2) \cdot \Sigma_2^{-1} =  \Sigma_1^{-1}\Sigma_0\Sigma_2^{-1}$, but I have no idea how to use it.

Hope anyone can give me some hints to complete the proof. Thank you very much!

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-14623-7_5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of computation, I figured it out myself. Here's the details.

Exponential of LHS is (omit the $-\pi$ factor)

$$
(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{c}_1)^t \Sigma_1^{-1} (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{c}_1) + (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{c}_2)^t \Sigma_2^{-1} (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{c}_2)
$$

Exponential of RHS is (omit the $-\pi$ factor)

$$
(\mathbf{c}_1-\mathbf{c}_2)^t \Sigma_0^{-1} (\mathbf{c}_1-\mathbf{c}_2) + (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{c}_3)^t \Sigma_3^{-1} (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{c}_3)
$$

Note that the term in RHS

$$
\begin{aligned}
(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{c}_3)^t \Sigma_3^{-1} (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{c}_3) 
&= \mathbf{x}^t \Sigma_3^{-1}\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{c}_3^t \Sigma_3^{-1}\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_3^t \Sigma_3^{-1}\mathbf{c}_3 + \mathbf{c}_3^t \Sigma_3^{-1}\mathbf{c}_3^t \\
&= \mathbf{x}^t(\Sigma_1^{-1}+\Sigma_2^{-1})\mathbf{x} - (\Sigma_3^{-1} \mathbf{c}_3)^t \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}^t(\Sigma_3^{-1} \mathbf{c}_3) + \mathbf{c}_3^t \Sigma_3^{-1}\mathbf{c}_3^t
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
(\Sigma_3^{-1} \mathbf{c}_3)^t \mathbf{x} =(\Sigma_1^{-1}\mathbf{c}_1+\Sigma_2^{-1}\mathbf{c}_2)^t \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{c}_1^t \Sigma_1^{-1} \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{c}_2^t \Sigma_2^{-1} \mathbf{x}
$$

$$
\mathbf{x}^t (\Sigma_3^{-1} \mathbf{c}_3)  =\mathbf{x}^t(\Sigma_1^{-1}\mathbf{c}_1+\Sigma_2^{-1}\mathbf{c}_2)  = \mathbf{x}^t \Sigma_1^{-1} \mathbf{c}_1  + \mathbf{x}^t \Sigma_2^{-1} \mathbf{c}_2
$$

After canceling the same terms in LHS and RHS, it is now equivalent to showing that

$$
\mathbf{c}_1^t \Sigma_1^{-1} \mathbf{c}_1 + \mathbf{c}_2^t \Sigma_2^{-1} \mathbf{c}_2 = (\mathbf{c}_1-\mathbf{c}_2)^t \Sigma_0^{-1} (\mathbf{c}_1-\mathbf{c}_2) + \mathbf{c}_3^t \Sigma_3^{-1} \mathbf{c}_3
$$

We can further cancel some terms in RHS. Consider

$$
\Sigma_3^{-1} = \Sigma_1^{-1} + \Sigma_2^{-1} = \Sigma_1^{-1} (\Sigma_1+\Sigma_2) \Sigma_2^{-1} = \Sigma_1^{-1} \Sigma_0 \Sigma_2^{-1} = \Sigma_2^{-1} \Sigma_0 \Sigma_1^{-1} \\
\implies \Sigma_3 = \Sigma_2 \Sigma_0^{-1} \Sigma_1 = \Sigma_1 \Sigma_0^{-1} \Sigma_2
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{c}_3^t \Sigma_3^{-1} \mathbf{c}_3 &= \mathbf{c}_3^t \Sigma_3^{-1} \; \Sigma_3 \; \Sigma_3^{-1} \mathbf{c}_3 \\
&=(\Sigma_1^{-1}\mathbf{c}_1 + \Sigma_2^{-1}\mathbf{c}_2)^t \; \Sigma_3 \; (\Sigma_1^{-1}\mathbf{c}_1 + \Sigma_2^{-1}\mathbf{c}_2) \\
& = \mathbf{c}_1^t \Sigma_0^{-1} \Sigma_2 \Sigma_1^{-1} \mathbf{c}_1  + \mathbf{c}_1^t \Sigma_0^{-1} \mathbf{c}_2^t + \mathbf{c}_2^t \Sigma_0^{-1} \mathbf{c}_1^t + \mathbf{c}_2^t \Sigma_0^{-1} \Sigma_1 \Sigma_2^{-1} \mathbf{c}_2
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore, the RHS equals to (note that the term $\mathbf{c}_1^t \Sigma_0^{-1} \mathbf{c}_2^t$ and $\mathbf{c}_2^t \Sigma_0^{-1} \mathbf{c}_1^t$ can be canceled)

$$
\begin{aligned}
& (\mathbf{c}_1-\mathbf{c}_2)^t \Sigma_0^{-1} (\mathbf{c}_1-\mathbf{c}_2) + \mathbf{c}_3^t \Sigma_3^{-1} \mathbf{c}_3 \\
= \; & \mathbf{c}_1^t (\Sigma_0^{-1} + \Sigma_0^{-1} \Sigma_2 \Sigma_1^{-1}) \mathbf{c}_1  + \mathbf{c}_2^t (\Sigma_0^{-1} + \Sigma_0^{-1} \Sigma_1 \Sigma_2^{-1}) \mathbf{c}_2 \\
= \; &\mathbf{c}_1^t (\Sigma_0^{-1} \Sigma_1\Sigma_1^{-1} + \Sigma_0^{-1} \Sigma_2 \Sigma_1^{-1}) \mathbf{c}_1  + \mathbf{c}_2^t (\Sigma_0^{-1}\Sigma_2\Sigma_2^{-1} + \Sigma_0^{-1} \Sigma_1 \Sigma_2^{-1}) \mathbf{c}_2 \\
= \; & \mathbf{c}_1^t (\Sigma_0^{-1} (\Sigma_1 + \Sigma_2) \Sigma_1^{-1}) \mathbf{c}_1  + \mathbf{c}_2^t (\Sigma_0^{-1}(\Sigma_2 + \Sigma_1) \Sigma_2^{-1}) \mathbf{c}_2 \\
= \; & \mathbf{c}_1^t \Sigma_1^{-1} \mathbf{c}_1  + \mathbf{c}_2^t \Sigma_2^{-1} \mathbf{c}_2 \\
\end{aligned}
$$
which is exactly the LHS.